# Jenkins BitBucket Error "[WARNING] Reference path does not exist: Bitbucket url" for submodule

Tags: android, jenkins, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have added git submodule to my project.
Now when I am setting up Jenkins, I am getting this error for submodule:

```bash
git submodule init # timeout=10
[WARNING] Reference path does not exist: Bitbucket Url
git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp ^submodule\.(.+)\.url # timeout=10
git config --get submodule.platforms/android/FolderName.url # timeout=10
git remote # timeout=10
git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.platforms/android/FolderName.path # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket for ParentProject
git submodule update --init --recursive platforms/android/FolderName # timeout=10
```

Although it clones and copies the entire submodule code.
What is this warning?

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated with [JENKINS-43894](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43894), it can be related to what you have set in  '`Advanced clone behaviours`' -> '`Path of the reference repo to use during clone`'

Either that field includes an environment variable (which was not resolved before [git plugin 4.0+](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/575)), or the URL itself declared in the `.gitmodule` of the main repository checked out by the Jenkins job is problematic.

Comment: Hi if the URL was the problem then it should not have cloned the submodule with all files.  Either that field includes an environment variable (which was not resolved before git plugin 4.0+), (this part i didnot understand)

Comment: @L.Learner Can you share the `.gitmodules` content?